# Magento add custom text in prices

Tags: magento

I'm trying to write the word "+IVA" in all the product prices. Where can I change that so I can have something like the following screenshot?:

[image]

Comment: What do you have currently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the text never changes, I'd just hard code it to the template, maybe in template/catalog/product/list.phtml after the getPriceHtml() line.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is using CSS property :after

```
.class:after {
content:"+IVA";
color:red;
font-size:12px;
}
```

You can style it however you want.

Answer (score 0):

In theme's product listing file (template/catalog/product/list.phtml) after `<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>` you can write '+IVA'. But you need to write it twice as there are list and grid view separate. So search for it and after that code write down '+IVA' text